# CodeIgniter Tutorial about Static Pages

Tags: php, codeigniter, static

I started to try the first tutorial example on http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/tutorial/static_pages.html.

I always get the Page Not Found Problem!
I have read a lot of articles about to solve the problem. But it doesn't matter how often I try the solutions in different forums, it's not working!

Can someone please let me know where my bugs are?

So these are some files I tried:

**My routes.php in application/config**

```
$route['default_controller'] = "pages/view";
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';
```

**My pages.php in application/controllers**

```
<?php
   class Pages extends CI_Controller{
    public function view($page = "home")
    {
      if ( ! file_exists('application/views/pages/'.$page.'.php'))
      {
        // Whoops, we don't have a page for that!
        show_404();
      }

      $data['title'] = ucfirst($page); // Capitalize the first letter

      $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
      $this->load->view('pages/'.$page, $data);
      $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);
    }
}
```

My home.php and about.php are on **application/views/pages/**
and the header.php and the footer.php are on **application/views/templates/**

Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you insert `var_dump($page); return;` before `if(!file_.....`? This way we check if this method starts.

Comment: Can you write what URL do you trying to open?

Comment: What if you just take out that `if(!file_exists)` and let CI handle the missing view how it already does anyway, and see what happens?

Comment: Ok now it works but this is very strange because the solution was to just try if it would work with wampp instead of xampp. I can not really say what was wrong but thank you very very much guys for your help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Take the file exists or not condition out,it will work,because what you are checking is not a file,but just an URL to route to. So obviosuly it will always return false,which will lead to failure of your work.

Answer (score 0):

In **application/config/routes.php**

**Try changing**

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'pages/view';
$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';
```

**To**

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'pages/views';
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

Hope it works. Worked for me though.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the code in **/application/config/routes.php** to:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "pages/view";
$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

CodeIgniter reads the code line by line, so its choosing to display the 404 page before the page you created.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to follow the directions closely. I was having the same problem and searched for a solution. Only after reading some of these answers did I realize that I hadn't created the `templates` or `pages` sub-directories within the `views` directory. By the time you get to the end of the [static pages](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/tutorial/static_pages.html) tutorial, you should have a structure as follows:

```
/views/
   /templates/
     header.php
     footer.php
   /pages/
     about.php
     home.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly run this

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

Then try this

```
$route['default_controller'] = "pages/view";
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

I had the same problem but not it solved.

Answer (score 0):

Create a .htaccess file in your project’s root directory and add the following code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```